# Typo3 11.5 Form Finishers Order

Tags: typo3-11.x

From this link https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/E/Finishers/Index.html it says `Finishers are executed in the order defined in your form definition.` which I believe is the yaml file where I define everything related to my form, in my case it's `contactUs.form.yaml`. In it I have defined 3 finishers:

```
finishers:
  -
    options: &cyberImpactFinisherOptions
      message: 'Merci pour votre message.'
      templateRootPaths:
        100: 'EXT:site_pgq/Resources/Private/Templates/Partial/'
      templateName: ContactThankYou
    identifier: CyberImpactFinisher
  -
    options: &emailToReceiverOptions
      subject: 'Nouveau message du site PGQ.ca'
      recipients:
        test@pgq.ca: test
      senderAddress: fdsfsa@ffds.com
      senderName: fdsfsa
      addHtmlPart: true
      attachUploads: true
      templateName: ContactUsForm
      translation:
        language: Default
      useFluidEmail: true
      title: 'Nouveau message!'
      templateRootPaths:
        100: 'EXT:site_pgq/Resources/Private/Templates/Email/'
      partialRootPaths:
        100: 'EXT:site_pgq/Resources/Private/Partials/Email/'
      layoutRootPaths:
        100: 'EXT:site_pgq/Resources/Private/Layouts/Email/'
    identifier: EmailToReceiver
  -
    identifier: FormToDatabase
```

You can see the order is: CyberImpactFinisher > EmailToReceiver > FormToDatabase

But when I output the result of `$this->finisherContext->getFormRuntime()->getFormDefinition()->getFinishers();` The order I get is EmailToReceiver > CyberImpactFinisher > FormToDatabase.

I believe the order of`getFinishers()` is the real one because if I do a `$this->finisherContext->cancel();` in the CyberImpactFinisher, the email is sent but the form is not saved in the database.

I would like to change the order of my finishers so that when I do `$this->finisherContext->cancel();` in the CyberImpactFinisher, the email will not be sent and the info not saved in the database, but I can't find how to change the order of the finishers.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution! The finishers in my `form.yaml` were properly ordered but the problem was that I used *variants* in my form and to keep using finishers you have to redefine them in the variant, and that's where my order was wrong. So fixing the order in my variants fixed my problem.